# How to implement Batch Normalization on tensorflow with Keras as a high-level API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, batch-normalization

BatchNormalization (BN) operates slightly differently when in training and in inference. In training, it uses the average and variance of the current mini-batch to scale its inputs; this means that the exact result of the application of batch normalization depends not only on the current input, but also on all other elements of the mini-batch. This is clearly not desirable when in inference mode, where we want a deterministic result. Therefore, in that case, a fixed statistic of the global average and variance over the entire training set is used.

In Tensorflow, this behavior is controlled by a boolean switch `training` that needs to be specified when calling the layer, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization. How do I deal with this switch when using Keras high-level API? Am I correct in assuming that it is dealt with automatically, depending whether we are using `model.fit(x, ...)` or `model.predict(x, ...)`?

---

To test this, I have written this example. We start with a random distribution and we want to classify whether the input is positive or negative. However, we also have a test dataset coming from a different distribution where the inputs are displaced by 2 (and consequently the labels check whether x>2).

```
import numpy as np
from math import ceil
from tensorflow.python.data import Dataset
from tensorflow.python.keras import Input, Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization

np.random.seed(18)
xt = np.random.randn(10_000, 1)
yt = np.array([[int(x > 0)] for x in xt])
train_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xt, yt)).shuffle(10_000).repeat().batch(32).prefetch(2)

xv = np.random.randn(100, 1)
yv = np.array([[int(x > 0)] for x in xv])
valid_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xv, yv)).repeat().batch(32).prefetch(2)

xs = np.random.randn(100, 1) + 2
ys = np.array([[int(x > 2)] for x in xs])
test_data = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xs, ys)).repeat().batch(32).prefetch(2)

x = Input(shape=(1,))
a = BatchNormalization()(x)
a = Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')(a)
a = BatchNormalization()(a)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(a)
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y, )
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_data, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=ceil(10_000 / 32), validation_data=valid_data,
          validation_steps=ceil(100 / 32))
zs = model.predict(test_data, steps=ceil(100 / 32))
print(sum([ys[i] == int(zs[i] > 0.5) for i in range(100)]))
```

Running the code prints the value 0.5, meaning that half the examples are labeled properly. This is what I would expect if the system was using the global statistics on the training set to implement BN.

If we change the BN layers to read

```
x = Input(shape=(1,))
a = BatchNormalization()(x, training=True)
a = Dense(8, activation='sigmoid')(a)
a = BatchNormalization()(a, training=True)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(a)
```

and run the code again we find 0.87. Forcing always the training state, the percentage of correct prediction has changed. This is consistent with the idea that `model.predict(x, ...)` is now using the statistic of the mini-batch to implement BN, and is therefore able to slightly "correct" the mismatch in the source distributions between training and test data.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, then yes, keras does automatically manage training vs inference behavior based on `fit` vs `predict`/`evaluate`. The flag is called `learning_phase`, and it determines the behavior of batch norm, dropout, and potentially other things. The current learning phase can be seen with `keras.backend.learning_phase()`, and set with `keras.backend.set_learning_phase()`.

https://keras.io/backend/#learning_phase

Comment: Thanks! That's the confirmation I needed. Only, I'm using Tensorflow and tf.keras, so the correct link to refer to is https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/learning_phase (no 1:1 equivalence between keras and tf.keras)

Comment: @GianlucaMicchi FYI, there is a dedicated tag for `tf.keras` (see edited tags)